# Firefox sounds doesn't work occasionaly in ubuntu 9.10

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-9.10

My firefox audio sometimes works and sometimes doesn't works in ubuntu 9.10. Whenever I restart my computer it works but after a while it doesn't work again! Can anybody help me to fix it?

Comment: Do you mean plugins running in firefox like Flash?